# Mostrar imagen gif de loading antes de mandar datos AJAX, jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Cuento con este código, pero no me funciona, ¿tengo error de sintaxis? También quiero validar el campo de correo, si es existente o si ya está registrado.

```
<script>
$(function()
{
    $('#registro_btn').on('click',function(e)//nombre del boton
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var correo = $('#correo').val();//nombre del input
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"adjunto/logica/registroUsuario.php",
            data('email='+correo),
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $('#loading').show();//nombre del .gif
            }
            success: function(respuesta)
            {
                //alert(respuesta);
            }
        })
    })
})  

</script>
```

El registro de usuario me funciona bien, lo que necesito es que al presionar el botón, muestre el loading.gif, ya agregué el 'sleep(2);' dentro de registroUsuario.php.

Comment: has probado a ponerlo fuera del ajax?

Comment: No te falta una coma después de la llave de cierre del `beforeSend`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay errores
en la peticion ajax, reemplaza estas lineas. Please.

```
       data:{'email':correo},
       beforeSend: function()
        {
            $('#loading').show();//nombre del .gif
        },
        success: function(respuesta)
        {
            //alert(respuesta);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
No es necesario usar sleep(2); ya que al utilizar ajax, se usa comunicacion Asincrona.
Al igual que invocas beforeSend, puedes invocar 
           complete:function(){
             $('#loading').hide();
           },
           error:function(){
            $('#loading').hide();
           }
```

Comment: Listo, ya quedó, sí me faltaba alguna coma y la sintaxis del data.